# Share a windows network printer in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, windows, printing

I want to share a windows network printer with Ubuntu 16.04. So, I'm trying to install the `smb service`, but the following message appears

```
itcell@itcellubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install python-smbc 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-smbc
itcell@itcellubuntu:~$
```

What can i do?

Comment: Have you tried `samba`

Comment: `python-smbc` is a library for python... what does that have to do with finding your printer?! Why not let the printers option in the menu scan for your printers?